# Maxima 02 gear stuck in neutral

Tags: nissan, manual-transmission, maxima

My manual transmission is stuck  on neutral I was driving on freeway when I exit and took out of 6th gear it would not go into any gear no noises does it make just wount go into any gear not even reverse. Any suggestions on what I can do my self before taking to shop? I appreciate any help.  Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is this a manual transmission?

Comment: Yes it is manual

Comment: Haha, I guess I could have just read the post ... sorry about that, lol.

Answer (score 2):

There are usually three possible things that I know of that prevent shifting between gears other than internal transmission problems. Hydraulic clutch master or slave cylinder issue or a bad clutch or God forbid all three at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for that. See I had the all those 3 parts replaced 3 months ago.  The clutch feels normal has pressure.

Comment: I remember before it gave out  while going into 6th gear it felt different than all other gears. It felt as if it was forcing to go in not smooth felt as if it was rubbing against both sides gearbox? And when going out of gear same difficult to take out of gear and felt as if it would go into 5th gear at times it would and I would go to neutral from 5th